# retrieving URL in iOS app

Tags: ios, url, networking

I need to display a homepage in my iPad application. I have been reading the URL Loading information on the Apple Developer site and am confused. In the sample code for SimpleURLConnections, they have a Python server. 
A colleague mentioned that it should be just a couple lines of code, so clearly I am missing something. There must be an easier way to do this, but I'm at a loss as to what that is.

Comment: Do you mean display a web page in your app? For that you would use UIWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be easy loading an external browser with cocoa touch. You could use UIWebview with your own browser, but it's easier this way.

This is from my own app:

```
- (IBAction)doSupportURL {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://webpages.charter.net/apollosoftware/support/"]];

}
```

with UIWebView see loadRequest

Comment: This is an excellent option, I do the same thing.